# A sequence of continuous functions and integration.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, sequence-of-function

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f_n : [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ be a continuous functions. Since, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the function $f_n$ is continuous, then $f_n$ is integrable. Hence, there exists a constante $M_n >0$ (depending of $n \in \mathbb{N}$) such that
$$\int_{a}^{b} f_n(x) \; dx < M_n.\tag{1}$$

**Question.** There exists $M>0$ (not depending of $n \in \mathbb{N})$ so that
$$\int_{a}^{b} f_n(x) \; dx < M, \; \forall \;  n \in \mathbb{N}? \tag{2}$$

It seems to me unlikely that happen, since we do not have more properties of functions $ f_n $, with $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, for instante, $ f_n $ is not necessarily bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about $f_n(x)=n$ for every $x \in [a,b]$ ?

(Note also that your last sentence is not correct : as continuous functions over $[a,b]$, all the $f_n$'s *are* bounded)

Comment: There is some assumptions over $f_n$ that made the sentence correct?

Comment: If the $f_n$ are *uniformly* bounded for example (i.e. there exists $C$ such that $\forall n, \forall x$, $|f_n(x)|\leq C$), the sentence is correct. Note that this is a sufficient but not necessary condition.

Comment: I agree, since in this case $$\int_{a}^{b} f_n(x)\; dx \leq \int_{a}^{b} C \; dx \leq (b-a)C=:M.$$

Comment: That's correct :)